# How to convert BigInteger to BigDecimal?

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

Is there any way to convert a `BigInteger` into a `BigDecimal`?

I know you can go from a `BigDecimal` to a `BigInteger`, but I can't find a method to go the other way around in Java.

Comment: you should accept answer at least

Answer (score 68):

You have a [parameterized constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.math.BigInteger%29) for that.

`BigDecimal(BigInteger val)`

Answer (score 29):

There is a [constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.math.BigInteger)) for that.

```
BigDecimal bigdec = new BigDecimal(bigint);
```

Answer (score 6):

> `public BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale)`
>
> Translates a `BigInteger` *unscaled value* and an `int` *scale* into a `BigDecimal`. The value of the `BigDecimal` is `unscaledVal/10^scale`.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `unscaledVal` - *unscaled value* of the `BigDecimal`.
> `scale` - *scale* of the `BigDecimal`.

<sup>[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.math.BigInteger-int-)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

I know this reply is late but it will help new users looking for this solution, you can convert BigInteger to BigDecimal by first converting the BigInteger into a string then putting the string in the constructor of the BigDecimal, example :

```
      public static BigDecimal Format(BigInteger value) {
          String str = value.toString();
          BigDecimal _value = new BigDecimal(str);
          return _value;
      }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Given that there exists already a constructor made specifically for this purpose (see other answers). I do not see any benefits that this approach offers.